# "При возможности" или всё-таки "по возможности"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги, смысл

Как правильно: ***при*** возможности или ***по*** возможности, если имеется в виду ***в том случае, если есть возможность, свободное время?*** Или вообще выражение неудачное и надо заменить? Чем? (Если есть лучшее выражение, но это всё же допустимо, хотелось бы разобраться с предлогом в любом случае.)

С одной стороны, вроде должно быть ***при*** (наличии) возможности, но есть устойчивое выражение ***по*** (мере) возможности, означающее *настолько, насколько человек справляется, насколько сил хватает.* Вот и возникает мысль: *а может, мой смысл тоже надо "впихнуть" в более распространённое выражение?*

Answer (score 2):

Предлоги употребляются в разных ситуациях: **по возможности** –  в соответствии с возможностью, **при возможности** – если есть возможность (свободное время и др.)

1) **По возможности, по мере возможности** (в соответствии с возможностью, насколько это возможно)

Нет, он должен был придумать какой-нибудь новый ход, да ещё, **по возможности**, красивый… [Вера Белоусова. Второй выстрел (2000)]

Готовясь к написанию статьи, журналист должен **по возможности** изучить тему. [Р. Н. Аджубей. О науке, о жизни и о себе // «Наука и жизнь», 2009]

Но постараемся, **по мере возможности**, трудоустроить их. [Никита Юрьевский. С толком, с чувством расстановка (2013.03.29) // «Новгородские ведомости», 2013]

2) **При возможности** (когда/если существует/появляется возможность)

Я думаю, половина желаний исчезнет **при возможности** осуществления. [М. А. Кузмин. Дневник 1934 года (1934)]

Это сделает, **при возможности**, любой порядочный человек. [Александр Розенбаум. Бультерьер (1987-1998)]

...самым любимым ее занятием было подсматривать и подслушивать, а также **при возможности** читать чужие письма. [Александра Маринина. Светлый лик смерти (1996)]

Comment: Спасибо! Забыл прочитать ответ, когда увидел, теперь исправился. Так если они обособляются, значит, это водные слова или как трактовать? Думал, что вообще не должно быть обособления. (Кстати, Вы так и не прокомментировали мою мысль о том, чтобы заменить слово в своём ответе на мой вопрос, который Вам понравился, а я ждал.)

Comment: Артем, я внесла изменение в предыдущий ответ. Что касается обособления, то эту тему можно посмотреть в справочнике http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_530  Грамота считает, что это наречное выражение, которое обычно не обособляется, но возможно авторское обособление со значением уточнения.

Answer (score 1):

Довольно интересный вопрос. Как я считаю, возможны оба варианта, однако употребляются  они в разных ситуациях:

1) Сочетание  "при возможности" я бы использовал как обособленное обстоятельство со значением условия:

*При соответствующей возможности, сделайте, пожалуйста, домашнее задание* (то есть данная конструкция может спокойно отсутствовать в предложении. На первый план выходит просьба. Как Вы сказали, здесь действительно помогает распространенность сочетания);

2) Здесь я хочу сказать, что данное сочетание относится к обыкновенному  обстоятельству, тесно связанному со сказуемым.

*По возможности  сделайте  домашнее  задание.* (Здесь акцент делается на том, что задание можно и не делать.)

В общем, употребление  определенного предлога зависит от значения и, соответственно, обособление данного сочетания.

P.s: мнение ученика средней школы, так что лучше почитайте и другие ответы.

UPD: спасибо за редактирование шрифта.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и за скромность! :)) Только обособлять, по-моему, их не надо. Не за что!)

Comment: Обособление таких конструкций зависит в основном от личного желания автора и от степени их распространенности. Также важную роль играет смысловая нагрузка, то есть обязательность/необязательность наличия в предложении. Источник(перефразировал содержание): Русский язык 8, Быстрова)